# Google Maps marker duplicate infoWindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

I am using Google Maps API and letting a user move a marker around a map by clicking. My goal is to listen to a click event, and when it happens, move the marker and update the infowindow (lat, lng information with click on the marker).

The following code "works", though it duplicates the infowindows (first click, you get one window, second click, you get the updated infowindow and the first one, etc). How would I go about deleting the previous instances of infowindow?

```
<script>
function myMap() {
var mapProp= {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng($latlng['lat'], $latlng['lng']),
    mapTypeId: 'satellite',
    zoom:$latlng['zoom']
};

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);


var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng($latlng['lat'], $latlng['lng']),
          map: map,
          title: 'Location'
        });

var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            '$latlng['address']'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';


var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
        });

marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

            placeMarker(event.latLng);
            var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            event.latLng.lat()+","+event.latLng.lng()+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';


            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      content: contentString
                    });

            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
        });

        function placeMarker(location) {



            if (marker == undefined){
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location,
                    map: map,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                });
            }
            else{
                marker.setPosition(location);
            }

        }

}
</script>
```

I tried various solution, notably adding a event.removeListener in there, to no avail (either no effect, or only the initial infowindow is used).

Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle, please?

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing is that infowindow has a SetContent function, and I was thus creating a new infowindow everytime by redeclaring a variable. Why they all reappeared after being closed, I'm not sure.

In the google.maps.event.addListener() function, replacing:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: contentString
                });
```

with a simple call to the setContent method:

```
infowindow.setContent(contentString);
```

fixed my issue.